# Как лучше хранить и загружать изображения в приложение на Android?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, android-room

Пишу небольшое приложение магазина одежды(первое более менее похожее на приложение). Вопрос следующий: Как правильно хранить изображения в базе данных? Допустим есть вещь, те же джинсы, и к ней 5 изображений. Все хранить на телефоне не вариант(насколько я понимаю), поэтому лучше, если на них есть ссылка, откуда мы уже и получаем изображение. Как лучше хранить эти ссылки в базе на телефоне? Массив строк подойдет? Использую Room.

Буду благодарен любому толчку, любой подсказке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильный способ - создание отдельной таблицы для хранения ссылок на картинки для статьи. И нужно сделать связь один-ко-многим меж таблицами товаров и картинок.

Таблица картинок должна выглядеть так:

1. id INT AUTOICREMENT
2. url TEXT
3. goods_id INT (c констрэинтом на `id` таблицы товаров)

При таком способе вы сможете хранить любое количество картинок для товара, получая их запросом вида:

```
select * from images where goods_id='ТУТ ID ТОВАРА'
```

---

Хранить или не хранить картинки - решать вам. Большинство библиотек для отображения картинок по умолчанию самостоятельно сохраняют картинки на телефон.

---

Отображать и хранить картинки можно либой `Glide`